# How to creat album using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've this generated URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=123005381082600|2.AtN22PtKsPB6tN_naD7ZWA__.3600.1298494800-602414132|4I62wGohikRAtIPYTU4jy7__I9A&type=post&name=refacingme
```

is this URL correct for creating an album using FB graph API , and what is the expected response for this request ?

Comment: i tried , but i don't understand the results , and i don't see any album has been created !!

Comment: Consider updating the question to reference the official documentation you've referenced, more details about what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL is for getting all the albums belonging to you.
If you want to create an album with FB api, you have to write some code:
1. step: login and get your token
2. step: create the album

Basically it's pretty simple.
Please check out at the related [docs here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/), and a [sample PHP code here](http://digitizor.com/2011/02/04/facebook-post-without-phpsdk/).

Comment: I've already logged in and got my access token ? but what is else ? how to do step 2 ???

Comment: create an array with two childs: 1. access_token, 2. name (value=the name of the album). then simply POST it with cURL to this URL: http://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/albums

Comment: if it's still not working, please paste your code and I'm sure we can find out what's the problem with it.